# Indefinite loops where the first time is different

Tags: algorithms, loops

This isn't a serious problem or anything someone has asked me to do, just a seemingly simple thing that I came up with as a mental exercise but has stumped me and which I feel that I should know the answer to already. There may be a duplicate but I didn't manage to find one.

Suppose that someone asked you to write a piece of code that asks the user to enter a number and, every time the number they entered is not zero, says "Error" and asks again. When they enter zero it stops.

In other words, the code keeps asking for a number and repeats until zero is entered. In each iteration *except the first one* it also prints "Error".

The simplest way I can think of to do that would be something like the folloing pseudocode:

```
int number = 0;
do
{
    if(number != 0)
    {
        print("Error");
    }
    print("Enter number");
    number = getInput();
}while(number != 0);
```

While that does what it's supposed to, I personally don't like that there's repeating code (you test number != 0 twice) -something that should generally be avoided. One way to avoid this would be something like this:

```
int number = 0;
while(true)
{
    print("Enter number");
    number = getInput();
    if(number == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        print("Error");
    }
}
```

But what I don't like in this one is "while(true)", another thing to avoid.

The only other way I can think of includes one more thing to avoid: labels and `goto`s:

```
    int number = 0;
    goto question;
error:
    print("Error");
question:
    print("Enter number");
    number = getInput();
    if(number != 0)
    {
        goto error;
    }
```

Another solution would be to have an extra variable to test whether you should say "Error" or not but this is wasted memory.

Is there a way to do this without doing something that's generally thought of as a bad practice (repeating code, a theoretically endless loop or the use of `goto`)?

I understand that something like this would never be complex enough that the first way would be a problem (you'd generally call a function to validate input) but I'm curious to know if there's a way I haven't thought of.

Comment: Why is "while(true)" a thing to avoid?

Comment: In this example it's not that important (because it's short) but in general, the best arguments against `while(true)` I've read are a)it makes it harder for a (human) reader to know what ends the loop and b)it makes it easier for future changes to remove the clause by mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following solution avoids repetition and separates the concerns of getting the input and validating it:

```
do
{
  print "Enter number"
  number = getInput()
} while(!numberValid(number))

bool numberValid(number) {
  if (number == 0) { 
    return true
  } else {
    print "Error!"
    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: One of the only uses I know of for putting the `while` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby I would consider this to be a guard clause and I would write it as either:

```
do_something if condition
```

or

```
do_something unless condition
```

I use these sparingly though.  If there is a lot of code (more than 2 statements or lines say) I prefer the traditional `if then else` construct.

The main time I use is is for short conditions so that I can write the single line:

```
procA if x=1
```

instead of the 3 lines:

```
if x=1 then
  procA
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd separate the two behaviours
The first is getting a number for the user, the second is validating it and eventually re-asking it
So I'd go like this

`int number = 0;
print "Enter number";
number = getInput();
while(number != 0) {
    print "Error!";
    number = getInput();
}`

Maybe you could not like the double input line, but I think it's a nice trade off

Comment: I'd say this has the same "problem" (for my personal tastes) as the original example. More so if you repeat the second "Enter number" line. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
int number;
while((number = solicitNumber()) != 0) {
    print("Error!");
}

...

int solicitNumber() {
    print("Enter number");
    return getInput();
}
```